# deleting cells in table View

Tags: iphone, tableview

I'm having a problem with my deleting of cells in the tableview , my program simply crashes when i press de delete button.

Here is my code for it :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object at the given index path
        sect = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [sect removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Update Event objects array and table view
        [listArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
        tableView.editing = YES;

        }
}
```

Comment: crashes with what ? EXC_BAD_ACCESS or SIGABRT array index out of bounds or what ?

Comment: Post the output of your crash log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the following completely:

```
sect = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[sect removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Just call `[listArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` then call `reloadData` to refresh your `UITableView`.